# i keep failing a basic mysql trigger statement

Tags: mysql, sql

for some reason this code in mysql doesn't work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER todays_plays BEFORE INSERT ON Games.`Plays`
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `TodaysPlays` TodaysPlays + 1;
```

**Edit:**

```
Table:Games
|Plays|TodaysPlays|                                                           

|  1  |    0      |
```

this is one table called Games, i want TodaysPlays to also increment as plays increments

this new code ive added works but doesnt target plays instead it targets the whole table games.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER todays_plays BEFORE INSERT ON Games
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.TodaysPlays = TodaysPlays + 1;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Edit;**

I have an event where today plays resets to 0 every day and i want it so that when plays is updated by 1 todays plays also does the same, however this code isn't working can someone help please.

in this example they are both in the same table, could someone also tell me how to do it when they are from different tables please, so that i can kill 2 birds with one stone.

To summarise, i want 1 (2 if your feeling generous) basic trigger statement.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Please explain your data structures and what the data looks like before and after.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand the question, its something basicly the same as how this sites views work, the moment the page loads, data is inserted into my sql, i could just use php and insert into todays plays aswell but ive been trying to learn triggers and ive been doing so for a couple weeks now.

Comment: Could you put your answer back up please so that others can also add their input on it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Your code was definately helpful as for the first time ever i now have a working trigger however it doesent target what i want it to target.                                
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER todays_plays BEFORE INSERT ON Games
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.TodaysPlays = TodaysPlays + 1;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;                                                                                                   However, i want to target a column inside the table games called playlater.

Comment: As I've already asked, edit your question.  Edit your question and add the definitions of your tables and what you want the data to look like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry i am struggling to make a good table, i hope you can understand what im trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

GUIDE:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER todays_plays
AFTER INSERT ON Games FOR EACH ROW
begin

//SAMPLE GUIDE CODE
///INSERT INTO TABLENAMEHRE (FIELD1,FIELD2) VALUES(NEW.VALUE1,NEW.VALUE2);



END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Otherwise if you want to modify with it's own table which is table name Games then:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER todays_plays
AFTER INSERT ON Games FOR EACH ROW
begin

//SAMPLE GUIDE CODE
///NEW.VALUE1 = NEW.VALUE1 + 1


END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: how would i do after insert on plays?

Comment: the NEW.VALUE1 AND NEW.VALUE2 from tablename Games would be inserted into TABLENAMEHRE

Comment: What is the name of the table you wanted to insert the new value.

Comment: The name of the table is games, the columns are play and TodaysPlays, i want to say on the update on plays, also update TodaysPlays. @reds.

Comment: How would i target the column plays and on the update (or insert) trigger increment TodaysPlays by 1?

Comment: You dont need this `AFTER INSERT` otherwise you need this `BEFORE UPDATE`